# Print multibyte characters to stdscr/program window NCURSES

Tags: c, ncurses, multibyte-characters

Currently I try to simulate matrix rain using C and NCURSES. I need to print multibyte characters to the program window using NCURSES.
I have function that return random chars 12784-12799 range from Unicode. These are Japanese characters converted from hex to decimal.

Then I use this function to print the characters with different location:

```
mvwaddch(mainwin, j, i*2, col-rows[i]);
```

col-rows[i] contains the randombly created number.

This approach does not work for now, program print ^@ ^A ^e ^B etc, instead of Japanese characters.
I believe I use a wrong function and mvwaddch does not accept multibyte characters.
If so, please let me know which NCURSES function could be used for this purpose.

Comment: *man ncurses* section on [*Initialization*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) mentions calling `setlocale` (which would make this a duplicate).

Comment: I use setlocale(LC_ALL, "")

Comment: There are prerequisites: a) linking with correct ncurses libreary - ncursesw, b) correct setting your environment - LC_CTYPE (`export LC_CTYPE=C.UTF8`).